# How to create a Dataframe from one Series, when it is not as simple as to transpose the object?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I've seen many similar questions here, but none of them applies to the case I need to solve. It happens that I have a `products` Series in which the names of the "future" columns end with the string `[edit]` and are mixed with the values that are going to be join in them. Something like this:

```
Index   Values
0       Soda [edit]
1       Coke
2       Sprite
3       Ice Cream [edit]
4       Nestle
5       Snacks [edit]
6       Lays
7       Act II
8       Nachos
```

I need to turn this into a df, to get sth like:

```
        Soda     Ice Cream     Snacks
0       Coke     Nestle        Lays
1       Sprite   NaN           Act II
2       NaN      NaN           Nachos
```

I made a Series called `cols_index`, which saves the index of the columns as in the first series:

```
Index   Values
0       Soda [edit]
3       Ice Cream [edit]
5       Snacks [edit]
```

However, from here I don't know how to get to *pass* the values to the columns. As I'm new to pandas I thought in iterating using a `for` loop generating ranges which would refer to the elements' indexes (`[1,2], [4], [6:8]`), but that wouldn't be a *pandorable* way to do things.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

=========================================================

EDIT: I solved it, here's how I did it.

After reviewing the problem with a colleague, we concluded that there's no pandorable way to do it and therefore, I had to use the data as a list and apply `for` and `if` loops:

```
products = pd.read_csv("products_file.txt", delimiter='\n', header = None, squeeze = True)
product_list = products.values.tolist()
cols = products[products.str.contains('\[edit\]', case = False)].values.tolist()   # List of elements to be columns

df = []
category = product_list[0]

for item in product_list:
    if item in cols:
        category = item[:-6]   # Removes '[edit]' 
    else:
        df.append((category, item))

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Category', 'Product'])
```

Answer (score 0):

We do `isin` find the column name , then with `cumsum` and `cumcount` create the pivot key then do `crosstab`

```
s=df1.Values.isin(df2.Values)

df=pd.crosstab(index=s.cumsum(),
               columns=s.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount(),
               values=df1.Values,
               aggfunc='first').set_index(0).T
0        Soda IceCream  Snacks
col_0                         
1        Coke   Nestle    Lays
2      Sprite      NaN   ActII
3         NaN      NaN  Nachos
```

Comment: Hi, I got an error on your first line, tried to solved on my own but I couldn't. Having that ```df2```is my ```cols_index``` (of type Series), when running the query I get the error message ```'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'```. I tried casting it to numpy but the cast marked another error. What is my mistake there?